# Sqlite database connection with c#

Tags: sqlite

Hi Am developing a windows phone app and using Sqlite DB and as a first step created login page. Now once i close my application the database does not persist and end up creating DB evertime the app opens followed by adding all values. How to i make it persistent and retain all values instead of adding them again and again?

Thanks
AV

Answer (score 1):

Save the database file in the isolated storage . this is the place you should save all your application data you need to persist for next executions